# Внести дополнительный параметр в скрипт

Tags: bash, mikrotik

День добрый! В наличии имеется башовый скрипт на роутере, переключающий провайдера с основного на резервный и наоборот. Скрипт рабочий, но попросили добавить туда дополнительный параметр avg rtt>50. Т.к. я совсем ещё зелень в баше, то прошу помощи. Куда можно запихнуть этот параметр, подскажите, пожалуйста? Код прикрепляю ниже.

```
#!/bin/bash    
hos=$(hostname)    
dat=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")    
t=$(date | cut -d " " -f5)   
interf=$(/usr/sbin/ip route show | grep -n 1 | grep "1:" | cut -d " " -f5) #check default interface    
tcf=$(timeout 3s ping -c 1 1.1.1.1 | grep time= | cut -d "=" -f4 | cut -d " " -f1 | cut -d "." -f1 ) #check CF dns resolver    
tg=$(timeout 3s ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 | grep time= | cut -d "=" -f4 | cut -d " " -f1 | cut -d "." -f1 ) #check google dns resolver    
tn=$tcf || $tg #check if one of dns providers in down, but internet is available    
#echo $tn    
if [[ -n $tn && $tn -lt 300 ]]; then #checking for ping >0 and ping time less 100 ms, if not - internet is down/weak    
echo "[$t] $hos connection check success, on $interf with CF $tcf and Google $tg $dat $interf" » /var/log/failover/failover$dat.log    
else    
if [[ $interf == *"eno2"* ]]; then #if eno1 is default interface, we need to change it to eno2 with failover provider    
/usr/sbin/ifup eno1 && sleep 5 #up reserve interface    
echo "[$]$hos primary interface is now eno1 $dat $interf" » /var/log/failover/failover$dat.log    
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{ "text": "'$hos' primary provider is now OBIT" }' 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/T1FRQ6K51/B01RCPMP940/8ybcgn..'
bash /opt/scripting/telegram 'primary provider is now OBIT'    
else    
/usr/sbin/ifup eno2 && sleep 5 #up interface   
echo "[$]$hos primary interface is now eno2 $dat $interf" » /var/log/failover/failover$dat.log
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{ "text": "'$hos' primary provider is now GIS" }' 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/T1FRQ6K51/B01RCPMP940/8ybcgn..'    
bash /opt/scripting/telegram 'primary provider is now GIS'    
fi    
fi
```

Comment: А не могли бы Вы этот скрипт привести в качестве кода, а не скриншота? Так будет проще и лучше остальным разобраться в коде и помочь Вам

Comment: @4500zenja один момент

Comment: А что за параметр `avg rtt` откуда он берется, из чего формируется?

Comment: @ipatev_nn после пинга обычно формируется.
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 23.781/26.828/34.904/4.114 ms

Comment: @JagoSevatar, тогда попробуйте командой `rtt_awg=$(ping -q -w5 -c5 8.8.8.8 | cut -s -d "/" -f5)` получить значение, а после добавить проверку на значение